# How to sort Excel table by its column

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table as shown below. How do I sort this table by arranging the columns in ascending date order?

[image]

Comment: I think an easy way would be to copy and transpose the data so columns become rows and vice versa. Then you can sort on the first column (date) and then transpose back.

Comment: @jamheadart while this works for smaller tables it might be useful to know that VBA's transpose method has a limitation of 65536 elements/cells. In case your array exceeds this limit, the extra data will **silently** cast away.

Comment: Good to know, I've not used transpose much, I would normally actually write something to rearrange the data (way more fun) but it seemed like this could be an easy fix for OP

Answer (score 3):

You can sort a data range left to right, but you cannot sort a table left to right. You need to convert a table to a range first, then you can apply the sort command with the option to sort left to right. After that, you can make the range into a table again.

The macro recorder will be helpful in establishing the correct code for the left to right sort. Fire it up, then in the sort dialog click "Options" and select "left to right". Select your sort row and finish the dialog. The code then looks along the lines of this:

```
Sub Macro2()
'
' Macro2 Macro
'

'
    Range("A1:D3").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=Range("A1:D1") _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
        xlSortTextAsNumbers
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:D3")
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Range("$A$1:$D$3"), , xlYes).Name = _
        "Table2"
    Range("Table2[#All]").Select
End Sub
```

Adjust to suit your scenario.

Comment: Hi I have tried using macro recorder and got the code similar to yours at above. however whenever I try to run the macro again, the error "A table can't overlap with another table" appear. Could you help on this pls?

Comment: Make sure there is no other table in the range that you try to turn into a table.